# Setting "Use Network Time" programmatically on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have a mobile application which was developed using .NET Compact Framework 3.5 and running on Windows Mobile 6.5

I want to prevent users to change date and time settings. Setting the "Use network time" option in Cellular Network properties satisfy my requirements but i want to enable this setting programmaticaly. Is there a way to do this via registry?

Note: I know i can do it manually by synchronizing the device's date with server date but i don't want to do this because in case the server's date changes, all devices will have the wrong date setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always go this way to find registry key changes for a setting you do manually: 
1. take a snapshot of the registry
2. manually change the setting
3. take another snapshot
4. compare the two snapshots.

(see also http://www.hjgode.de/dev/installer/index.htm)

Luckily you find the responsible registry key for the setting. Mots of the reg keys have 'talking' names.

NITZ setting maybe implemented differently by the OEM, but you may try these reg keys (and reboot):

HKLM\Drivers\BuiltIn\RIL\DisableSyncTime DWORD=1 disables NITZ by WWAN

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\RIL:NitzEnable and UseNITZTimeAtStartup (provided by MS site)

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sierra Wireless\System]
"AutoUpdateTime"=dword:00000000

You see there are a plenty of different implementations.